# How to write this SQL select in JPA JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have a *Table*, call it **REI_BODY**, and I have an another, call it **REI_AMT_INFO**. I have a select in **oracle pl/sql**:

> SELECT 
>         *,
>
> ```
>   (SELECT AMT    FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '01') AMT_01,
>   (SELECT AMT    FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '02') AMT_02,
>
>   (SELECT SGN_CD FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '01') SGN_01,
>   (SELECT SGN_CD FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '02') SGN_02,
>
> FROM REI_BODY T
> ```

This is the REI_AMT_INFO table, ***no foreign key!***:

```
REI_ID (Number);
AMT_TYPE_CD (Varchar);
AMT (Number);
SGN_CD (Varchar);
```

I have to create this select in JPA JPQL language. How could I do this?

Comment: Obviously JPQL is based around classes and fields, and you haven't shown any. Have a thought about how you expect anyone to answer that. While you're at it, tell people what you've tried and what result you got.

Comment: without knowing table name you can use Named Query in a class or xml ,Am I right .If am wrong please correct me.

Comment: JPQL involves class names, field names ... and a named query simply puts the JPQL in an annotation or XML so you still have to know the class names and field names. All basic JPA docs and the JPA spec reveal this

Answer (score 1):

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="REI_BODY",
    query="SELECT *,

  (SELECT AMT    FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '01') AMT_01,
  (SELECT AMT    FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '02') AMT_02,

  (SELECT SGN_CD FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '01') SGN_01,
  (SELECT SGN_CD FROM REI_AMT_INFO I WHERE I.REI_ID=T.REI_ID AND AMT_TYPE_CD = '02') SGN_02,

FROM REI_BODY T"
)
```

[CHECK THE LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)

Comment: which isn't "JPQL" that the OP asked for

Comment: then please answer for his Question.